# Find possible coordinates of a triangle that I know only the sides length

Tags: triangles, coordinate-systems

I want to find the possible coordinates of each vertex of a triangle of which I know only the sides lengths like $(3,4,5)$.

To find the first edge, I let $E_1=(0;0)$ and the second $E_2=(3;0)$. but I have a problem to find the 3rd vertex.

How can I find the 3rd ?

I know that we can find the angles with trigonometry but it's only for a right triangle, so I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: why didn't take $E_3=(0,4)$?

Comment: But if it’s not a right triangle ? Sorry...

Comment: I'm typing something as answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The vertices may be $\quad (0,0)\quad (3,0)\quad (3,4)\quad $. The last vertex could also be $\quad (0,4).\quad$ No need for knowing angles or trig. Draw a pic and you will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let in triangle $ABC$, we know the side lengths $AB=c$, $AC=b$ and $BC=a$. We look for coordinates of vertices $A$, $B$ and $C$.

So, without loss of generality, we can take $B=(0,0)$, and then $C=(0,a)$ because $BC=a$.
We located to vertices $B$ and $C$ and we need only locate vertex $A$. To do so, suppose the circles $$x^2+y^2=c^2\quad \text{and}\quad (x-a)^2+y^2=b^2$$
then the intersection of this two circles gives the location of $A$.

Note that we have $$x^2+y^2=c^2\quad \text{and}\quad x^2+y^2-2ax+a^2=b^2$$
therefore $$c^2-2ax+a^2=b^2$$
or $$x=\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2a}$$
and thus since $x^2+y^2=c^2$, $$y=\pm\sqrt{c^2-\frac{(c^2+a^2-b^2)^2}{4a^2}}$$
and the coordinates of $A$ is
$$\left(\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2a},\pm\sqrt{c^2-\frac{(c^2+a^2-b^2)^2}{4a^2}} \right)$$
well, you can choose one of the signs $\pm$.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: hey :) i've transcripted to c# and it didin't worked. I just switched your x and y and it works !!! Have you a explanation ?

Comment: But thank you i better understand now

Comment: @WitzigAdrien You'r welcome polite guy